# why not vertically aligned in the forest

Tags: forest

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt},
    child/.style={align=center,text width=2.8cm,fill=green!50,rounded corners=6pt},
    grandchild/.style={fill=pink!50,text width=1.5cm}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={%
    thick,
    drop shadow,
    l sep=0.6cm,
    s sep=0.8cm,
    node options={draw,font=\sffamily},
    edge={semithick,-Latex},
    where level=0{minimum height=1cm,parent}{},
    where level=1{
        minimum height=0.8cm,
        child,
        parent anchor=south west,
        tier=p,
        l sep=0.25cm,
        for descendants={%
            grandchild,
            minimum height=0.6cm,
            anchor=150,
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                (!to tier=p.parent anchor) |-(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
        }
    }{},
}
[developmental %\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em} 
[two parts
    [cognition
    [cognition developmental
        ]
    ]
]
[four part
    [social
        [physical
            [action
                [language
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It comes from `anchor=150,` in `where level=1`. If you comment it out, then they are all aligned.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! (I added an answer, which I will be happy to remove if you say so. On the other hand, it may not be obvious to everyone that the horizontal position of the `.150` anchor depends on the ratio `height/width`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is the key `anchor=150` in `where level=1`. Why does it move the lowest node node in the left branch and not others? Because the lowest has a height that differs from the heights of the other grandchildren. Therefore the `anchor=150` has a different horizontal position (relative to the center of the node) than all of the others, which have all the same height. As a consequence, the relative position is shifted. So you may want to drop this key.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt},
    child/.style={align=center,text width=2.8cm,fill=green!50,rounded corners=6pt},
    grandchild/.style={fill=pink!50,text width=1.5cm}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={%
    thick,
    drop shadow,
    l sep=0.6cm,
    s sep=0.8cm,
    node options={draw,font=\sffamily},
    edge={semithick,-Latex},
    where level=0{minimum height=1cm,parent}{},
    where level=1{
        minimum height=0.8cm,
        child,
        parent anchor=south west,
        tier=p,
        l sep=0.25cm,
        for descendants={%
            grandchild,
            minimum height=0.6cm,
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                (!to tier=p.parent anchor) |-(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
        }
    }{},
}
[developmental 
[two parts
    [cognition
    [cognition developmental]
    ]
]
[four part
    [social
        [physical
            [action
                [language
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]